# Google Place API keyword vs name

Tags: google-places-api, google-places

I am using the Google Places API and I am making a request that looks like this.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=[LOCATION]&radius=500&keyword=[STORE_NAME]&key=[API_KEY]
```

The issue is that when I use the keyword in the request, the keyword looks for the value I provide in the name, address and anywhere else in the google content for a place. How can I do it so that I can give the store name and have it only search in the name field. I don't care about looking in the address.

Let me know if this doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Places API Radar Search has just been deprecated, and will be retired in a year.

Please see full details in blog post [Removing Place Add, Delete & Radar Search features](https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2017/06/announcing-deprecation-of-place-add.html).

On a related note, for both Radar Search and Nearby Search, the `name` parameter is just [equivalent](https://google-developers.appspot.com/places/web-service/search#RadarSearchRequests) to `keyword`:

> `name` — A term to be matched against all content that Google has indexed for this place. Equivalent to `keyword`. The `name` field is no longer restricted to place names. Values in this field are combined with values in the `keyword` field and passed as part of the same search string. We recommend using only the `keyword` parameter for all search terms.